# dropdownlist populate gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am using the wizard in Visual Studio to define the a data source that populates a dropdownlist.   This is working fine.   Then I have a second datasource that should filter data from another table using the selected value from the dropdownlist and display it in a gridview.   When I make my selection in the dropdownlist I thought the gridview should changed automatically to show the new filtered data.  But it is not.   Seems like I am missing an auto post back or something like that.    Below is the code I am using.

```
<form id="appointmentform" runat="server">

<div class="wdn-band" id="findpersonband" runat="server" visible="true">
    <div class="wdn-inner-wrapper wdn-inner-padding-sm">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SNR_InformationConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [personnelid], [lastname] FROM [tblmasterpersonnel] ORDER BY [lastname], [preferredfirstname]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="MasterPersonnelDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="lastname" DataValueField="personnelid"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SNR_InformationConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [personnelid], [startdate], [endingdate], [employeetypeid], [dateentered] FROM [tblappointmentdate] WHERE ([personnelid] = @personnelid)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="MasterPersonnelDDL" Name="personnelid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="startdate" HeaderText="startdate" SortExpression="startdate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="endingdate" HeaderText="endingdate" SortExpression="endingdate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="employeetypeid" HeaderText="employeetypeid" SortExpression="employeetypeid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dateentered" HeaderText="dateentered" SortExpression="dateentered" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

may be you could use

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MasterPersonnelDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="lastname" DataValueField="personnelid" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```